# What determines which assembly version is built into the bin folder

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-assembly

I have referenced directly a NuGet package x with v5.0.

Another NuGet package that I reference has this x package referenced but with version v4.0.

What determines which assembly version is built into the bin folder?

Answer (score 2):

In your case *v5.0* of package *x* is restored
and the matching target framework lib copied to your application's output path,
due to the [Nearest Wins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#nearest-wins) rule,
which resolves the version of the package closest to your app in the dependency graph.
When referencing different package versions having the same distance to your application, then the [Cousin Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#cousin-dependencies) rule applies.

To "see" which version is resolved using Visual Studio, go to your project in the *Solution Explorer* and expand **Dependencies | Packages**.
Alternatively, you may use [dotnet list package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-list-package) to list the package references for a project, or use `dotnet list package --include-transitive` to additionally get a list of packages that the top-level packages depend on.

Comment: My test project references the nuget v4.0 but still v5.0 is copied to the bin folder because the test project references a class library having installed nuget v5.0 Does a direct project reference count more than a direct package reference? But that would not be more near...

Comment: @HelloWorld All `PackageReference`s are put into the package graph, both direct and via `ProjectReference`s.
The scenario you have described in your comment differs from the one of your original question: Now _v4.0_ is closer to your app than _v5.0_ and therefore _v4.0_ is resolved.
But this now results in a **"detected package downgrade"** warning: _NuGet Warning [NU1605](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605)_.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer of FlashOver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63235449/52277) is correct for newer PackageReference csproj  format(aka .Net Core format).A full algorithm (including
the Nearest Wins and the Cousin Dependencies rules)
described in  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#dependency-resolution-with-packagereference.

The algorithm is  less predictable with older packages.config format (aka .Net Framework format).

> With packages.config, NuGet attempts to resolve dependency conflicts
> during the installation of each individual package…
>
> Each new package installation requires a traversal of the whole graph and raises the
> chance for version conflicts…
>
> When a conflict occurs, installation is stopped, leaving the project in an indeterminate state, especially
> with potential modifications to the project file itself.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#dependency-resolution-with-packagesconfig